# Show tables like 'year%' >=2010

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I've got database with tablenames

```
year200801
year200802
year200803
year201010
year201101
year201203
year201204
year201205
....
```

And now I need to get tables where `year > date('Y')-2`.
How to do that?

```
"show tables like 'year%' AND $year>='year2012';"
```

Comment: in MSSQL it's possible to compare strings. So year2010 should be 'less' than year2012. so "show tables where 'year' + $year >= 'year2012';" should possibly work.

Answer (score 5):

Ouch, this is an unfortunate schema to be working with.  You're best off in the long run to do away with these date-dependent table names.  However, you can get it from `information_schema`:

```
SELECT
  TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA='your_database_name'
  /* LEFT() should be faster than LIKE */
  AND LEFT(TABLE_NAME, 4)='year'
  /* The 4 char substring in the middle of the table name is >= 2 years ago */
  /* Use YEAR(NOW()) to get the current year */
  AND MID(TABLE_NAME, 5, 4) >= (YEAR(NOW()) - 2)
```

#### Update:

To show tables between 2 years ago and the current year, use:

```
  AND MID(TABLE_NAME, 5, 4) BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 2) AND YEAR(NOW())
```

#### Update 2 This should be working exactly as you ask for:

```
mysql> SELECT yearstring, MID(yearstring, 5, 4) BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 2) AND YEAR(NOW()) FROM tmp;
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| yearstring | MID(yearstring, 5, 4) BETWEEN (YEAR(NOW()) - 2) AND YEAR(NOW()) |
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| year201001 |                                                               1 |
| year201005 |                                                               1 |
| year201205 |                                                               1 |
| year201301 |                                                               0 |
| year201112 |                                                               1 |
| year201304 |                                                               0 |
| year200912 |                                                               0 |
| year200901 |                                                               0 |
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: ok, but it's seems that you forgot about months because this query not return any of table :(
ahh, and I need to show tables beetwen years (date('Y') -2) AND (date('Y')

Comment: @breq The months are not relevant to this query - you ask for the equivalent of `date('Y') - 2`. If you need to account for months, please clarify your question.

Comment: I need to get all table names where name (year) is between current year and two years ago including all months.
for example year201001, year201002... year201101,year201102,year201103,...year201201,year201202,year201203...

Comment: I've asked it 3 years ago! :D Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @breq I noticed a +1 on this old answer yesterday. I suspect you did too on the question and that's what brought you back to it?

Answer (score 4):

```
Show tables LIKE 'year201%'
```

will list all tables in the range 2010-2019, and if you have 202x:

```
Show tables LIKE 'year202%'
```

Comment: I need to show tables beetwen years (date('Y') -2) AND (date('Y') :(